# fprintf in a while loop will only print my data 10 times to a file

Tags: c, loops, printing

ran into a problem regarding fprintf, we want to write a double array into our file for every loop in our main's while loop, however when this loop goes higher than 10 it simply stops fprintf'ing.
The function in question is "store_trash_file". Also the program is controlled by a few defines at top.

Day_max = controls the amount of loops in our while loop
SIZE = with higher SIZE it seems it will fprintf less, and with a smaller it will fprintf more lines.

Ill be putting up the entire code, so u can run it, perhaps keep an eye on the create directories function, as it will make folders and some txts

**Any help is much appreciated**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <process.h>


#define MARGIN 70
#define MARGIN2 30
#define NAREA 4
#define NSUBAREA 4
#define SIZE 20
#define DAY_MAX 20
#define AREAS_PER_TRUCK 4
#define LOWER1 6
#define LOWER2 8
#define LOWER3 10
#define UPPER1 8
#define UPPER2 10
#define UPPER3 12

typedef struct subarea
{
    int co2_cost, time, emptied_subarea_counter, lower_random, upper_random, activity_level;
    double average, total_trash_subarea_avg, sensorData[SIZE], sensorDataTotal[SIZE];
} subarea;

typedef struct area
{
    subarea *subarea_array[NAREA + 1];
    double average, total_trash_area_avg;
    int emptied_area_counter;
} area;

void simulated_days(area *area_dynamic, area *area_static);
void average_trash(area *area);
void sensor_data_start(area *area, double start_var);
void compare_trash_to_empty(area *area_array[NAREA + 1], int *area_number_p);
void empty_trash(area *area, int *co2_counter_p, int *time_counter_p);
void store_trash_file(area *area_array[NAREA + 1]);
void create_areas(area *area_array[NAREA + 1]);
void empty_trash_static(area *area, int *co2_counter_static_p, int *time_counter_static_p);
void create_directories();
void make_txt_file(char file_name[30], char file_name2[30]);

int main(void)
{
    int co2_counter = 0, time_counter = 0;
    int co2_counter_static = 0, time_counter_static = 0;
    int day_counter = 0;
    int area_number;
    int garbage_truck_amount = 0;
    double *area_array_avg[DAY_MAX][NAREA];
    double *subarea_array_avg[DAY_MAX][NAREA * NSUBAREA];
    double *trashcan_array_avg[DAY_MAX][NAREA * NSUBAREA * SIZE];
    
    
    area *area_array[NAREA + 1];
    area *area_array_static[NAREA + 1];

    srand(time(NULL));
    
    for (int i = NAREA; i > 0; i -= AREAS_PER_TRUCK)
    {
        garbage_truck_amount++;
    }
    printf("Garbage trucks: %d\n", garbage_truck_amount);

    create_areas(area_array);
    create_areas(area_array_static);
    
    create_directories();

    int running = 1;
    while (running)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < NAREA + 1; i++)
        {
            simulated_days(area_array[i], area_array_static[i]);
            average_trash(area_array[i]);
            average_trash(area_array_static[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < NAREA + 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < NSUBAREA; j++)
            {
                printf("area array: %lf\n", area_array[i]->subarea_array[j]->average);
                printf("area array static: %lf\n", area_array_static[i]->subarea_array[j]->average);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < garbage_truck_amount; i++)
        {
            compare_trash_to_empty(area_array, &area_number);
            empty_trash(area_array[area_number], &co2_counter, &time_counter);
            
            for (int j = 1; j < NAREA + 1; j++)
            {
                average_trash(area_array[j]); 
            }
        }

        if (day_counter > 1 && day_counter % 14 == 0)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < NAREA + 1; i++)
            {
                empty_trash_static(area_array_static[i], &co2_counter_static, &time_counter_static);
                average_trash(area_array_static[i]);
            }
        }

        store_trash_file(area_array);
        printf("Day: %d\n", day_counter + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < NSUBAREA; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < NAREA + 1; j++)
            {
                printf("%lf\t", area_array[j]->subarea_array[i]->average);
                printf("%lf\t", area_array_static[j]->subarea_array[i]->average);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n"); 

        day_counter++;
        if(day_counter == DAY_MAX) 
        {
            running = 0;
        }
    }
}

void simulated_days(area *area_dynamic, area *area_static)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NSUBAREA; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            int x = ((rand() % (area_dynamic->subarea_array[i]->upper_random - area_dynamic->subarea_array[i]->lower_random + 1)) + area_dynamic->subarea_array[i]->lower_random);
            area_dynamic->subarea_array[i]->sensorData[j] += x;
            area_dynamic->subarea_array[i]->sensorDataTotal[j] += x;

            area_static->subarea_array[i]->sensorData[j] += x;
            area_static->subarea_array[i]->sensorDataTotal[j] += x;
        }
    }
}

void average_trash(area *area)
{   
    double sum[NSUBAREA];
    double sum_total[NSUBAREA];
    double area_trash_sum = 0;
    double area_trash_sum_total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < NSUBAREA; i++)
    {
        sum[i] = 0;
        sum_total[i] = 0;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < NSUBAREA; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            sum[i] += area->subarea_array[i]->sensorData[j];
            sum_total[i] += area->subarea_array[i]->sensorDataTotal[j];
        }
        area->subarea_array[i]->average = sum[i] / SIZE;
        area->subarea_array[i]->total_trash_subarea_avg = sum_total[i] / SIZE;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NSUBAREA; i++)
    {
        area_trash_sum += area->subarea_array[i]->average;
        area_trash_sum_total += area->subarea_array[i]->total_trash_subarea_avg;
    }

    area->average = area_trash_sum / NSUBAREA;
    area->total_trash_area_avg = area_trash_sum_total / NSUBAREA;
}

void sensor_data_start(area *area, double start_var)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NSUBAREA; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            area->subarea_array[i]->sensorData[j] = start_var;
            area->subarea_array[i]->sensorDataTotal[j] = start_var;
        }
    }
}

void compare_trash_to_empty(area *area_array[NAREA + 1], int *area_number_p)
{
    int highBlock = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < NAREA + 1; i++)
    {
        if (area_array[i]->average >= MARGIN)
        {
            if (area_array[i]->average > area_array[highBlock]->average)
            {
                highBlock = i;
            }
        }
    }
    *area_number_p = highBlock;
    printf("\nhighblock %d\n", highBlock);
}

void empty_trash(area *area, int *co2_counter_p, int *time_counter_p)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NSUBAREA; i++)
    {
        if (area->subarea_array[i]->average > MARGIN2)
        {
            *co2_counter_p  += area->subarea_array[i]->co2_cost;
            *time_counter_p += area->subarea_array[i]->time;
            area->subarea_array[i]->average = 0;
            area->subarea_array[i]->emptied_subarea_counter++;
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
            { 
                if (area->subarea_array[i]->sensorData[j] <= 100) 
                {
                    area->subarea_array[i]->sensorData[j] = 0;
                }
                else if (area->subarea_array[i]->sensorData[j] > 100) 
                {
                    area->subarea_array[i]->sensorData[j] -= 100;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    area->emptied_area_counter++;
}

void store_trash_file(area *area_array[NAREA + 1])
{
    // int xcount = 0;
    // int ycount = 0;
    // double area_array_avg[NAREA];
    // double subarea_array_avg[NAREA * NSUBAREA];
    // double trashcan_array_avg[NAREA * NSUBAREA * SIZE];

    FILE *output_filepointer;

    char *dirname2 = "C:\\Users\\jacob\\Documents\\software\\projekter\\p1\\kode\\intelligenttrash\\data\\area";
    char newdirname[150];
    char newdirname2[150];
    char newdirname3[150];

    for (int i = 1; i < NAREA + 1; i++)
    {
        // area_array_avg[i - 1] = (area_array[i]->total_trash_area_avg);

        snprintf(newdirname, 150, "%s%d\\area_average_total.txt", dirname2, i);
        output_filepointer = fopen(newdirname, "a");
        fprintf(output_filepointer, "%lf ", area_array[i]->total_trash_area_avg);

        for (int j = 0; j < NSUBAREA; j++)
        {
            // subarea_array_avg[j + (ycount * NSUBAREA)] = (area_array[i]->subarea_array[j]->total_trash_subarea_avg);

            snprintf(newdirname2, 150, "%s%d%s%d\\subarea_average_total.txt", dirname2, i, "\\subarea", j);
            output_filepointer = fopen(newdirname2, "a");
            fprintf(output_filepointer, "%lf ", area_array[i]->subarea_array[j]->total_trash_subarea_avg);

            for (int z = 0; z < SIZE; z++)
            {
                // trashcan_array_avg[z + (xcount * SIZE)] = (area_array[i]->subarea_array[j]->sensorDataTotal[z]);

                snprintf(newdirname3, 150, "%s%d%s%d\\trashcan_trash.txt", dirname2, i, "\\subarea", j);
                output_filepointer = fopen(newdirname3, "a");
                fprintf(output_filepointer, "%lf ", area_array[i]->subarea_array[j]->sensorDataTotal[z]);
            }
            // xcount++;
            fprintf(output_filepointer, "\n");

            output_filepointer = fopen(newdirname2, "a");
            fprintf(output_filepointer, "\n");
        }
        // ycount++;

        output_filepointer = fopen(newdirname, "a");
        fprintf(output_filepointer, "\n");
    }
    fclose(output_filepointer);
        
}


void create_areas(area *area_array[NAREA + 1]) 
{
    int percentage_added[3][2] = {{LOWER1, UPPER1}, {LOWER2, UPPER2}, {LOWER3, UPPER3}};
    int activity_level;

    for (int i = 0; i < NAREA + 1; i++)
    {
        area_array[i] = malloc(sizeof(area));

        for (int j = 0; j < NSUBAREA; j++)
        {
            activity_level = (rand() % 3);
            area_array[i]->subarea_array[j] = malloc(sizeof(subarea));
            area_array[i]->subarea_array[j]->co2_cost = 50;
            area_array[i]->subarea_array[j]->time = 50;
            area_array[i]->subarea_array[j]->average = 0;
            area_array[i]->subarea_array[j]->emptied_subarea_counter = 0;
            area_array[i]->subarea_array[j]->total_trash_subarea_avg = 0;
            area_array[i]->subarea_array[j]->lower_random = percentage_added[activity_level][0];
            area_array[i]->subarea_array[j]->upper_random = percentage_added[activity_level][1];
            area_array[i]->subarea_array[j]->activity_level = activity_level;

        }
        sensor_data_start(area_array[i], 0);
        area_array[i]->average = 0;
        area_array[i]->total_trash_area_avg = 0;
        area_array[i]->emptied_area_counter = 0;
    }
}


void empty_trash_static(area *area, int *co2_counter_static_p, int *time_counter_static_p)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NSUBAREA; i++)
    {
        *co2_counter_static_p  += area->subarea_array[i]->co2_cost;
        *time_counter_static_p += area->subarea_array[i]->time;
        area->subarea_array[i]->average = 0;
        area->subarea_array[i]->emptied_subarea_counter++;
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        { 
            if (area->subarea_array[i]->sensorData[j] <= 100) 
            {
                area->subarea_array[i]->sensorData[j] = 0;
            }
            else if (area->subarea_array[i]->sensorData[j] > 100) 
            {
                area->subarea_array[i]->sensorData[j] -= 100;
            }
        }
    }
    area->emptied_area_counter++;
}

void create_directories() 
{
    int check;
    char *dirname1 = "C:\\Users\\jacob\\Documents\\software\\projekter\\p1\\kode\\intelligenttrash\\data";
    char *dirname2 = "C:\\Users\\jacob\\Documents\\software\\projekter\\p1\\kode\\intelligenttrash\\data\\area";
    
    
    mkdir(dirname1);

    for (int i = 1; i < NAREA + 1; i++)
    {
        char newdirname[100];
        char newdirname2[100];
        snprintf(newdirname, 100, "%s%d", dirname2, i);
        mkdir(newdirname);
        
        for (int j = 1; j < NSUBAREA + 1; j++)
        {
            snprintf(newdirname2, 100, "%s%d%s%d", dirname2, i, "\\subarea", j);
            mkdir(newdirname2);
        }
        
    }
}

void make_txt_file(char file_name[30], char file_name2[30])
{
    FILE *output_filepointer;

    char *dirname2 = "C:\\Users\\jacob\\Documents\\software\\projekter\\p1\\kode\\intelligenttrash\\data\\area";
    char newdirname[100];
    char newdirname2[100];

    for (int i = 1; i < NAREA + 1; i++)
    {
        if (file_name != "none")
        {
            snprintf(newdirname, 100, "%s%d\\%s.txt", dirname2, i, file_name);
            output_filepointer = fopen(newdirname, "a");
        }
        
        for (int j = 1; j < NSUBAREA + 1; j++)
        {
            if (file_name2 != "none")
            {
                snprintf(newdirname2, 100, "%s%d%s%d\\%s.txt", dirname2, i, "\\subarea", j, file_name2);
                output_filepointer = fopen(newdirname2, "a");
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(output_filepointer);
}
```

Comment: You've got 3 nested `for` loops each with `fprintf` calls. Exactly which one are you talking about looping > 10 times?

Comment: @lurker
Im talking about all of them.

it's being called in a while loop in main that runs to day max

now with how we imagined it each of those 3 for loops would be printing its data on 1 line in each of their txts. Then when the first call of the function ends, it makes a newline. and each run in our while loop is equal to 1 day, so this way we can tell our data apart day by day in the txt.

The problem is day_max = 15 should mean 15 lines in the txt, yet it stops after 10.
If we set day_max to under 10 it runs to the correct amount of times

Comment: A quick look through the function, it seems like you are doing `fopen` on a lot of files, but not calling `fclose` on all of them. The continuous reuse of `output_filepointer` is in the nested loops looks suspicious.

Comment: @lurker

This was actually it, for some reason thought the last fclose would close them all, but that makes no sense. This fixed it, tyvm.